# push notification leading to browser - Apple's policy

Tags: ios, browser, apple-push-notifications, push

Is there a standard for this...
Want to send push notifications with content leading to the current "specials".
The app doesn't keep up with dynamic content of said specials (they change 1-2 per week).
Is it good to use push notification to connect to app user, but, then go from push msg. right to the browser which is already programmed to show the updated dynamic new 'specials'.
Thoughts?  Apple's HIG view on this (push --> browser) ?

Advice?

Tried:  push notification that didn't have deep linking --> led to the app's home screen